# How can i filter csv column with Talend

Tags: talend

I want to filter a column, so that it return only row with 'walid' values
so here what i did, but it actualy return no row inside csv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHqQl.png)

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this

```
!Relational.ISNULL(row1.Nom)  && row1.Nom.trim().toLowerCase().equals("walid")
```